# SQL Selecting from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following two tables...

[image: Tables]

I am trying to select all the cities belonging to a country using the country name, or using the country id but displaying only the city name and country name.

I am using the following statement but is not working, this is my first time doing SQL

```
SELECT CI.CITY_NAME, CO.COUNTRY_NAME
FROM CITY CI INNER JOIN COUNTRY CO
ON CI.CITY_ID = CO.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE CO.COUNTRY_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Re-read this `ON CI.CITY_ID = CO.COUNTRY_ID` part of your query :-).

Comment: Yes.. change inner join columns as ON CI.COUNTRY_ID = CO.COUNTRY_ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing a country id with a city id, seems like you'd really want to do;

```
SELECT CI.CITY_NAME, CO.COUNTRY_NAME
FROM CITY CI INNER JOIN COUNTRY CO
ON CI.COUNTRY_ID = CO.COUNTRY_ID
WHERE CO.COUNTRY_ID = 1;
```

Comment: Ah i see the logic, thanks very much :) is there any other way of obtaining the same results without using inner join. Thanks

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos Well, for this exact problem you could just do `SELECT CITY_NAME FROM CITY WHERE COUNTRY_ID=1`. If you want to use both tables, there are other syntaxes but combining them in this way is by definition a JOIN.